# How can I send a parameter from a filter to a controller?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, servlet-filters

I need to pass a username object from filter to the controller. The controller is intended for those two parameters, but the parameters can not filter out posts.

The method in filter:

```
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
    /*send object to controller*/
    Username username = value; 
    response.sendRedirect("/create-bank-profile");
}
```

In controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create-bank-profile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView register(
    HttpSession session,
    HttpServletRequest request, 
    @RequestParam(required = false, value = "bank-info-check", defaultValue = "false") Boolean isBankCustomer,
    @RequestParam("accessKey") Long accessKey, 
    @RequestParam("secretKey") Long secretKey
) {
     /* access the username object's two fields: aceesskey and secretKey */

}
```

I think I must put this value to request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below commented code did not work.

```
    //RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("./test1");
    //rd.forward(request, response);
    //chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Then I tried like below. It is working fine. Please try with this. It should defiantly work.

I have tested the below code using servlets. I have add like "./test1".

In case of your scenario, you do not need to mention "./ " you can just say "required url"

```
        request.setAttribute("anil", "anil123");
        RequestDispatcher rd= ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestDispatcher("./test1");
        rd.forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `create-bank-profile` is a `POST` method and it's not possible to send a `POST` request using `response.sendRedirect()`.

You could probably check something from these options:

- Using `RequestDispatcher`

  ```
  request.setAttribute("param", "param value");
  RequestDispatcher dispatcher = servletContext().getRequestDispatcher(required_url);
  ```
- Set the required parameters in the request and use:

  ```
  response.setStatus(307);
  response.addHeader("Location", "required URL");
  ```

Comment: My problem still exist

Answer (score 0):

request.getRequestDispatcher("URL").forward(request, response);